# psycopg2.DataError type date invalid syntax

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, syntax-error, psycopg2

Looking to ingest data into a PostgreSQL (UTF-8) read into Pandas from a CSV (UTF-8) using the `read_csv` module in Pandas.

code snippet:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import dateimport locale
locale.getpreferredencoding(True)

df = pd.read_csv(full_path, encoding='utf-8-sig', sep=';')
for col in date_cols:
    if col in df.columns:
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
           date_con = df.ix[index, col]
           if isinstance(date_con, unicode):
               py_date = datetime.strptime(str(date_con), '%d.%m.%Y')
               if py_date > pd.Timestamp.max:
                   df.ix[index, col] = pd.Timestamp.max
               else:
                   x = py_date
                   df.ix[index, col] = x.date()
dict_items = df.to_dict(orient='records')
connection.execute(table.insert(), dict_items)
```

Error message is:

```
(<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'>, DataError('(psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for type date: ""\nLINE 1: ...hsing@redline.de\', \'1983-03-12\'::date, \'D\', \'\', \'\', \'\'...\n                                                             ^\n',), <traceback object at 0x1100ef050>)
```

One row example of `dict_items`:

```
{u'fname': u'Henry', u'sback':'', u'birthdt': datetime.date(1983, 3, 12), 'input': datetime.date(2017, 12, 27), u'email': u'hsing@redline.de', u'lname': u'Sting', u'country': u'DE', u'date_end': datetime.date(2019, 11, 12)}
```

I cannot figure out what is incorrect with the date syntax here. Any ideas what I can check or change?

Comment: Can you provide a value of `dict_items` variable before inserting?

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko - added the example up to. Thanks!